# Given some polygon drawn on a clock: how many distinct edges and polygons it contains?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, cyclic-groups

I'm creating polygons by stretching strings between numbers on the face of a clock. Those strings represent edges and they create polygons.

I'd like to know how many of those edges, triangles, quadrilaterals (etc.) are distinct.

For instance, in Ex. 1, I get 6 total edges:
$$\{0,3\} \{3,6\} \{6,9\} \{9,0\} \{0,6\} \{3,9\}$$

However, **only 2 edges are distinct: $|3|$, and $|6|$.**

Similarly, I get 4 triangles:
$$\{0, 3, 6\} \{3, 6, 9\} \{6, 9, 0\} \{9, 0, 3\}$$
Yet they are all of the form $(|3|, |3|, |6|)$. Therefore, I have 4 total triangles, and **only 1 distinct triangle.**
[image]

Here's another example.
[image]
In Ex. 2, **only 3 edges are distinct** and **only 2 triangles are distinct**.

Final example 3, has **only 5 distinct edges**, and **all of its triangles are distinct**.
[image]

**Here's the question:**
Given the coordinates (on an m-faced clock) of some polygon of n-sides, how can you **determine the number of the distinct edges and polygons**?

Comment: From the algebraic-geometry tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry." Please pay attention to tag usage guidance when tagging your questions.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not a mathematician, and I just guessed which tags might be relevant.

Comment: As your examples show, the answer is not just a function of $m$ and $n$; it depends on the particular polygon. So are you looking for an algorithm that takes the polygon as input? Or some total or average over all possible polygons?

Comment: I'm looking for the algorithm that takes the polygon as an input. I clarified the question at the end.

Comment: Not sure I understand the goal. You determine the counts by writing out the chord lengths, the chord lengths used by each subset of the vertices, and counting, just like you've done. Are you looking for a more efficient analysis for cases with many points?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the comment, I'm looking for a more efficient way to approach this. The iterative approach feels somewhat silly, but perhaps it's the best I've got..

Comment: The better name is [cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cyclic_quadrilaterals) with vertices shared with a regular polygon.

Comment: I do agree with the previous comments... it depends on the polygon, actually. The answer is not fixed.

Comment: @Somos, this needs to be applied to any polygon, even with 15 sides. or more.

Comment: @JetfiRex, right, I'm looking for an algorithm

Comment: For an algorithm... I don't think there is an efficient (for example, runtime in polynomial of $m$ and $n$) algorithm there, and I even suggest this problem is kind of NP-hard-ish...

Comment: Fair enough... :(